Nuget Package Downgrade Error without changing versions
I am receiving the following warning:
NU1605: Warning as error: Detected package downgrade: ....
For context, in ProjectA, I have installed OpcUaCore. However, internally, OpcUaCore uses many other packages, such as System.Memory 4.5.5, Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3, etc.
The issue is that ProjectA is referenced into many other projects, potentially hundreds.
The dependent projects use Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2, System.Memory 4.5.4.. etc.
It is not a viable solution to upgrade their packages, they are all explicitly using their selected versions via <PackageReference .. /> and I have been tasked to do this without changing any of the versions in the dependent projects.
I have tried using nuget.config, package version ranges and having the package binaries output to a completely separate folder, all of which have not worked.
I have also tried reading a lot of the previous StackOverflow posts on this particular issue, but in almost all of the cases, the suggestions are to use PackageReference in the problematic projects, which is not a viable option for me.
Is there any way to fully isolate ProjectA and only really make changes within that project only, leaving the others untouched?
